# How to do emote tricks on a Tumbler?

Tags: destiny

So with the EV30 Tumbler you can obviously do tricks by holding <kbd>R2</kbd> and using the left stick, but in the promotional movie you can see Guardians doing other tricks such as switch, superman and no-hands.

How are these performed?

Using the D-pad seems to only cause my Guardian to wave in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On EV30, use D-pad buttons when **in the air**, this will trigger different tricks.
On the ground D-pad does standard directional gestures that no one uses =)

Comment: So I have to hold R1 + R2, Left stick and press d-pad at the same time? What am I an octopus?!

Comment: Just get that thing in the air. After that the only buttons you need are D-pad arrows, which you can press with any hand\tentacle you like.

Comment: Surely the point is to do a backflip superman!